# How to implement edit form with file upload

Tags: html, node.js, reactjs, postgresql, react-router

Trying to update a form without uploading a new image. I'm
using multer for the image upload. it works very well when i
create a form.

I'm using reactJs for frontend and node for the server side.

**This is the front end code with react**

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";
import useFetch from "./fetch"; 

function EditForm() {  
    const { id } = useParams();
    const { contestant: form, error, isPending } = 
    useFetch("http://localhost:5000/dashboard/form_single/" + 
    id);
    
    const [name, setName] = useState('');
    const [address, setAddress] = useState('');
    const [fileName, setFileName] = useState('');

    useEffect(() => {
        setName(form.full_name);
        setAddress(form.home_address);
    }, [form])
    
        const editForm = async (id) => {
          try { 
            const formData = new FormData();
            formData.append("name", name);
            formData.append( "home_address", address);
            formData.append("image", fileName);

            const myHeaders = new Headers();
            myHeaders.append("jwtToken", localStorage.jwtToken);
      
            await 
fetch(`http://localhost:5000/dashboard/form_update/${id}`, {
              method: "PUT",
              headers: myHeaders,
              body: formData,
            });

          } catch (err) {
            console.error(err.message);
          }
        };

        const onChangeFile = e => {
          setFileName(e.target.files[0]);
        }

    return (
        <div>
            { isPending && <div>Loading...</div> }
            { error && <div>{ error }</div> }
            <form encType="multipart/form-data" 
             onSubmit={() => editForm(form.form_id)}>
                 <input
                  type="text"
                  className="form-control"
                  value={name || ''}
                 onChange={e => setName(e.target.value)}
                 />
                  <input
                  type="text"
                  className="form-control"
                  value={address || ''}
                  onChange={e => setAddress(e.target.value)}
                  />
                   <input
                   type="file"
                   id="update"
                   name="image"
                   onChange={onChangeFile}
                   />
                    <button type ="submit" >Save</button>
                    </form>
                    <div>
                      <img 
                      alt="contestant" 
          src= {`http://localhost:5000/upload/${form.passport}`} 
          className="rounded-circle" style={{width: "100px", 
           height: "100px"}}/>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
}

export default EditForm;
```

UNFORTUNATELY I GET `Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'filename')`. I've tried to make multer image upload optional but it did'nt work. The code bellow is the api.

**This is the server side code. Nodejs**

```
router.put("/form_update/:id", upload.single('image'), async(req, 
res) => {
    try { 
       const { id } = req.params;
       const image = req.file.filename;
       const { name, home_address } = req.body;
       
      const updateForm = await pool.query("UPDATE form SET 
       full_name = $1, home_address = $2, passport = $3 WHERE 
       form_id = $4 
       RETURNING *", [name, home_address, image, id]);
        
       res.json("Form was updated");
      } catch (err) {
        console.error(err.message);
      }
});
```

how do i not always have to change image everytime i need to edit a form.

Answer (score 0):

on the server, check if fields are provided, and then store values for each, and construct query dynamically, and when done checking, execute query

you could list fields in an array and then iterate them and construct query and values against `req.body`

you could also add some validation (check if there is id etc., you could add that on the front-end as well)

try this:

```
router.put("/form_update/:id", upload.single('image'), async(req, res) => {
  try {

    // fields. same as in req.body
    const fields = ['full_name', 'home_address', 'something', 'else'];

    // store values
    const values = [];

    // dynamic query string
    let stmt = [];

    const {id } = req.params;

    // add some validation
    if(!id) {
      console.error('no id..');
      return res.json({msg:"err: no id"});
    }

    const image = req.file ? req.file.filename : '';

    // build query
    fields.map((field)=>{

      if(req.body[field]) {
        values.push(req.body[field]);
        stmt.push(`${field} = $${values.length}`);
      }
    });

    // check image, as it's not in req.body
    if(image) {
      values.push(image);
      stmt.push(`passport = $${values.length}`);
    }    


    // no data..end
    if(!values.length) {
      console.log('no data..');
      return res.json({msg:'no data..'});
    }


    // finish
    stmt = "UPDATE form SET " + stmt.join(', ');
    
    values.push(id);
    stmt += ` WHERE form_id = $${values.length}`;

    stmt += ' RETURNING *';

    const updateForm = await pool.query(stmt, values);

    res.json({msg:"Form was updated"});

  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err.message);
  }
});
```

Comment: thank you very much. It showed an error "syntax error at or near "home_address". Though I used postman to test it.

Comment: @AyobamiAjibola what node version are you using

Comment: @AyobamiAjibola check your code, just copy paste route code, it's probably something else elsewhere..

Comment: figured out why it was showing the error. But i still cant save without uploading an image. I then used the image validation  this=>" image = req.file?.filename;"..  from the code you sent with the old code, i noticed that now it saves the changes of other fields to the database but passport field is null. Is there a way i can maintain the old image in the database when i click on save after editing other field without sending null to the passport field. Thank you.

Comment: @AyobamiAjibola something might've slipped through.. add `console.log(stmt)` right before update query. `passport` is not supposed to be included, if there is no image..

Comment: I added console.log(stmt)  as you said i got this response (UPDATE form SET full_name = $1, home_address = $2,  WHERE form_id = $3 RETURNING *)  without inserting the image. And it also return this error (
syntax error at or near "WHERE").

Comment: @AyobamiAjibola yes, commas were missing.. try the updated code

Comment: It works thank you. I'm greatfull. Though i've more fields, i know you said i should list them in an array but would there any effect on the code if i use if blocks? thank you once again.

Comment: @AyobamiAjibola great. yes, you could, but that would be ugly. I've added the loop. add fields to `fields`, but they must be the same as in `req.body`. image block will remain, because it's not within `req.body`